# Django Designing Models for Dating App Matches

Tags: django, django-models

I’m working on a dating app for a hackathon project.  We have a series of questions that users fill out, and then every few days we are going to send suggested matches.  If anyone has a good tutorial for these kinds of matching algorithms, it would be very appreciated. One idea is to assign a point value for each question and then to do a 
    def comparison(person_a, person_b) function where you iterate through these questions, and where there’s a common answer, you add in a point. So the higher the score, the better the match.  I understand this so far, but I’m struggling to see how to save this data in the database.

In python, I could take each user and then iterate through all the other users with this comparison function and make a dictionary for each person that lists all the other users and a score for them.  And then to suggest matches, I iterate through the dictionary list and if that person hasn’t been matched up already with that person, then make a match.

```
person1_dictionary_of_matches = {‘person2’: 3,  ‘person3’: 5,  ‘person4’: 10,  ‘person5’: 12, ‘person6’: 2,……,‘person200’:10}
person_1_list_of_prior_matches = [‘person3’, 'person4']
```

I'm struggling on how to represent this in django.  I could have a bunch of users and make a Match model like:

```
class Match(Model):
     person1 = models.ForeignKey(User)
     person2 = models.ForeignKey(User)
     score = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Where I do the iteration and save all the pairwise scores.

and then do
    person_matches = Match.objectsfilter(person1=sarah, person2!=sarah).order_by('score').exclude(person2 in list_of_past_matches)

But I’m worried with 1000 users, I will have 1000000 rows in my table if do this.  Will this be brutal to have to save all these pairwise scores for each user in the database? Or does this not matter if I run it at like Sunday night at 1am or just cache these responses once and use the comparisons for a period of months?  Is there a better way to do this than matching everyone up pairwise?  Should I use some other data structure to capture the people and their compatibility score? Thanks so much for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. In machine learning's current paradigm you work with sparse matrices that means that you would not have to perform every single match evaluation. The sparsity may come from two alternatives:

1. Create a batch offline analysis of your data to perform some clustering (fancy solution).
2. Filter the individuals by some key attributes: a) gender/sexual preference, b) geographical location, c) dating status etc. (simple solution)

After the filtering you could perform a function for estimating appropriate matches for the new user. Based on the selected choices of the user adscribe selected matches into the database for future queries. However, if you get serious about this problem I suggest you give Spark a try. This is not a problem for an SQL database but for a Big Data Engine.